# Multiple tables containing one entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on a system that sells products. This system has products, with subclasses for every producttype.

```
public abstract class Product 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string naam { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
}

public class Card :Product
{
    [Display(Name = "Cardnumber")]
    public int nummer { get; set; }
    public Kaliber kaliber { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, i want to keep a history of all the products i sold with all the data that was correct at that moment.

```
 public class Transaction
{
    public int transactionId { get; set; }
    public Member member { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> producten { get; set; }
    public double totaalprijs { get; set; }
    public DateTime tijdstip { get; set; }
    public string kantoorMedewerker { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that entity now makes a FK in Product to Transaction. That's not what i want. I want a seperate table for each of them; a Products table and a SoldProducts table. 
I already tried this in my productContext:

```
public DbSet<Product> producten { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product> uitgifte_producten { get; set; }
```

That's not possible, because EF doesn't allow multiple object sets per type .
This seems like something trivial, but i can't figure it out. 
Making two classes, one Product and one Soldproduct, with both of having subclasses of the producttypes, seems rather ugly. I tried it, but VS2012 complains that it can't converty Product to SoldProduct.

What seems to be a good idea to do this in C#, .net 4.0 and EF?

Comment: this is code first right?

Comment: Google "table per type code first EF". This will give you a Product table and then a card table(with all card and product fields )

Comment: Yes, it's Code First indeed. But the TPT won't help me, because i need both the "new" and the "old" product. Not only the Product can change, but also the Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just link to products from your transaction class using a basic many-to-many relationship?

Using EF Fluent API, you can add a config class with the following:

```
public class TransactionConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionConfig ()
    {
        this.HasMany(t => t.Products)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("TransactionId");
                x.MapRightKey("ProductId");
                x.ToTable("TransactionProducts");
            });
    }
}
```

Then, override the OnModelCreating function of you DbContext with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TransactionConfig());

}
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try this yet, but it seems that this could be the answer, if it works. If this indeed makes another table with Product, with the name TransactionProducts, that would be the best solution

Comment: Sorry, i was on holiday for some time. But it tested it, and it seems to indeed create the correct table. Only problem is that i now get a NullReferenceException when i try to add a product to a transaction.

    Transaction t = new Transaction();

            t.kantoorMedewerker = "gerard";


            db.transacties.Add(t);

            foreach (Product product in wachtrij)
            {
              t.producten.Add(product);
              db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
              db.SaveChanges();
            }

Comment: On which statement do you get the NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using EF Code First.
When you have a collection of products in your Transactions table, EF will take this to be a typical one to many relationship.

I would add a TransactionDetail table to which I would copy all the details I need from Product:

```
 public class TransactionDetail{
     public int TransactionId { get; set; }
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public string naam { get; set; }
     public string barcode { get; set; }
}
```

### Update in response to comment:

Still assuming you are using code-first. In your scenario, you could use the TransactionDetail class above as a base class then have more derived classes in respect to the types of products. You will be able to capture all the required details per product and you will only have one more extra table in your db.

Comment: I already considered that, but i have many more product types that extend Product, and having all that in one class seems rather dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do something like this in EF.

If you really want to keep all the product data for each transaction, I'd suggest creating product copies for every transaction and then storing them in the DB and referencing them from the transaction. You might also think about creating a self-reference on product, which could then point to the "actual product" for "transaction products".

Another approach I can think of is storing the product history instead of creating a copy of the product, i.e. creating product copies on product change instead of on transaction creation. This way, when creating a transaction you always link to the current version of your product.